# Sine Parametric function exercise

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, optimization, periodic-functions

Find the biggest negative value of $a$ , for which the maximum of

$f(x) =sin(24x+\frac{πa}{100})$ is at $x_0=π$

The answer is $a=-150$, but I don't understand the solving way. I would appreciate if you'd help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the general solution of $\sin\theta = 1$ is:
$$
\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n, \text{where }n \in \mathbb Z
$$
So the general solution for finding all maximum values of $f(x)$ is:
\begin{align*}
24x + \frac{\pi a}{100} &= \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n, \text{where }n \in \mathbb Z \\
24x  &= \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi a}{100} + 2\pi n, \text{where }n \in \mathbb Z \\
x  &= \frac{1}{24} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi a}{100} + 2\pi n \right), \text{where }n \in \mathbb Z \\
\end{align*}
In particular, we know that there is some $n_0 \in \mathbb Z$ such that $x_0 = \pi$, so:
\begin{align*}
\pi  &= \frac{1}{24} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi a}{100} + 2\pi n_0 \right) \\
24\pi  &= \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi a}{100} + 2\pi n_0 \\
\frac{\pi a}{100}  &= \frac{\pi}{2} - 24\pi + 2\pi n_0 \\
a  &= -2350 + 200 n_0 \\
\end{align*}
Since $a < 0$, we know that $n_0 < \frac{2350}{200} = 11.75$. Rounding down to the nearest integer, we find that $n_0 = 11$ so that $a = -2350 + 200(11) = -150$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Comment: Everything is clear. Thank you for taking your time to help me

Answer (score 3):

The problem involves determining the closest maximum of $\sin(24x)$ to $x_0 = \pi$ and then shift the curve to the right amount to put it in $x_0 = \pi$.

Maximums are at the points $x=\frac{1}{48}(4\pi\cdot n + \pi)$ so you have that the closest maximum is at $n= 11$ so $x_{closest} = \frac{45}{48}\pi$

This means that you have to shift the curve to the right by $\frac{3}{48}\pi$ to respect the condition that the maximum is in $x_0 = \pi$. Can you finish from here? (you can use $x = y - \frac{3}{48}\pi$ to shift the curve )

Comment: Well I was thinking like this: 24π+πa/100=π/2+2πn. After I simplified it, I got that 
2350=200n-a.
As you said, the closest maximum was at n=11. If we put 11 in here, the answer is correct
But can you tell me why 11 in more detail? I really want to figure this out

Comment: Oh man, the answer was right here all along. I have done tons of exercises like that and could have found the n, but I always think about some extraordinary methods when it comes to exercises like this and forget the simple ones. Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway it is about the fact you're using the general solution ( $11$ is the closest integer)

Comment: Read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for what to do in this cases

Comment: LOL, It tells me that I need 15 reputation to vote. Currently I have 11, but as soon as I reach it I will vote, won't forget